# How to get current page url in ftl file

Tags: angular, angular5, keycloak, freemarker, web-developer-toolbar

My code is looks like this:

```
                    <li class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountListLinkClass!}"><a href="http://localhost:4200/" id="zocial-${p.alias}" class="zocial ${p.providerId}"> <span>Sign in using OTP</span></a></li>
```

the problem is that, I need to send the current window url as  query param with the localhost:4200/ . How do I do that ? the file is of FTL Type.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post the code relevant for the paging.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by accessing Servlet Request object using:

```
${springMacroRequestContext.requestUri}
```

Which will return/print `/help` if the ftl was a page with URL `http://www.example.com/help`
The object `springMacroRequestContext` is a representation of `RequestContext` class:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestContext.html

**However**, I see you are not using Spring MVC or Spring Boot thus I'm afraid you can't use it, so why not just do it with Javascript:

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406208/6111835) for more options.